# notify-send: send notification from script running as root

Tags: desktop-environment, daemon, notifications, notify-send

In my desktop environment, I am using `dunst` as notification daemon, and I can send notification as:

```
notify-send "some message"
```

I have a terminal window open, where I am logged in as root, and I have backup script running. I would like to receive notification when the script completes.

How can I send notification as root, when I am logged in as regular user?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure `dunst` is installed on root if your case is root and run:

```bash
 myScript.sh && notify-send "some message"
```

if you didn't receive a notification then the script didn't return 0 code AKA it failed.

to get notification in case of failure you can run:

```bash
myScript.sh && notify-send "some message" || notify-send "script failed!"
```